# Can the Deathlock Mastermind's Grave Bolts be used to attack a single target twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack, targeting

In *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* (p. 129), the [**Deathlock Mastermind**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/deathlock-mastermind) has the following attack:

> ***Grave Bolts.*** *Ranged Spell Attack:* +6 to hit, range 120 ft., one or two targets. *Hit:* 18 (4d8) necrotic damage.

Can the Mastermind attack one creature with two bolts in a single round? Or is this specifically different from multiattack so that the Mastermind gets the benefit of multiple attacks if multiple targets are present?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes it can, given the update in *Monsters of the Multiverse*.

The Deathlock Mastermind was updated in *Monsters of the Multiverse*, and [*Modenkainen's Tome of Foes* is now obsolete](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/196284/62294). With this update, instead of Grave Bolts saying "one or two targets", it is now "Grave Bolt", having "one target", and is included in the Multiattack action:

> ***Multiattack.*** The deathlock makes two Deathly Claw or Grave Bolt attacks.
>
> ***Grave Bolt.*** *Ranged Spell Attack:* +6 to hit, range 120 ft., one target. *Hit:* 13 (3d8) necrotic damage.

So when the Deathlock uses Multiattack, it can just pick the same target for each attack with Grave Bolt.

Answer (score 13):

### RAW: it can only attack a single target with one bolt

Despite the fact that this seems to modeled after the Warlock's Eldritch Blast (which *can* attack the same target multiple times), **there is no special rule** that allows the monster to attack a target twice with the same attack.

---

For reference, Eldritch Blast states the following:

> The spell creates more than one beam when you reach higher levels. [...] You can direct the beams at the same target or at different ones. Make a separate Attack roll for each beam.

You'll notice that this clarifying text is missing from the text for the Deathlock Mastermind's Grave Bolts.